# CSS IE7 How can I force UL inside LI to be wider than the parent

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I have a drop down menu and it works perfectly except for Internet Explorer 7. Thank you MS.

For demonstration purposes I created this simple HTML. The dropdown menu is open to quickly illustrate the problem. In IE 7 the dropdown menu is cut to the width of the top level menu. In IE8 and IE9 this is not a problem.

I can fix the issue by adding the following javascript:

element.style.width = 320px

Works perfectly, however I need this done automatically like IE8 or IE9 would do, otherwise I have to calculate each dropdown width separately.

HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        ul.menu {list-style:none;font:10px Trebushet MS;font-weight:bold;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;left:86px;top:90px;line-height:100%;height:15px}
        ul.menu * {margin:0;padding:0;cursor:pointer}
        ul.menu .header {position:relative; float:left;color:#999999;padding: 3px 12px 2px 4px;white-space:nowrap}
        ul.menu .header ul {position:absolute; top:15px; left:0;background:#f0f0f0; overflow: hidden;list-style:none}
        ul.menu .header ul li {position:relative; padding: 3px 25px 3px 10px; white-space:nowrap; display: block}
        ul.menu .header ul li:hover {background-color:#dcdcdc}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li class="header">
        CREATE
        <ul>
            <li>A really really long description of nothing valuable</li>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test2</li>
            <li>test3 and again very long</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        SEARCH
        <ul>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow property set for the  the nested ul is the cause here. Removing the `overflow: hidden` property from `ul.menu .header ul` should correct this.

See a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b45rA/1/embedded/result/. You may need to use the run again command (top right) to render the output as jsfiddle doesn't play that nice with IE7.